# There is a way to write TREE(3) via $F^a(n)$?

Tags: trees, big-numbers, hyperoperation

I read about Graham number and `TREE(3)`.
Graham number is: $f^{64}(4)$ where $f(n)=3\uparrow^n 3$

My question is: If there is a way to write `TREE(3)` via $f^a(b)$?
(and of course $f(n)$ can be different, but at the form of:  $ x\uparrow^yz $)

Thank you!

Comment: To clarify : Do you mean the pure existence of such a number $a$ , or that a "reasonable-sized" $a$ does the job ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [explicit upper bound of TREE(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811602/explicit-upper-bound-of-tree3)

Comment: Concerning the question whether we can hit $TREE(3)$ EXACTLY , this is currently unknown and might never be known. But I agree to Arthur that chances are almost $0$ that a function of the kind you want does, unless you start with $TREE(3)$ which would however be "cheating"

Comment: Not sure about whether [tag:hyperoperation] is an appropriate tag here. But [number theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/number-theory/info) certainly isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $TREE(3)$ is in a completely different league. Graham's number has level $f_{\omega+1}$ in the fast-growing hierarchy, $TREE(3)$ is far beyond level $f_{\Gamma_0}$

So, the index $a$ in the function you want to arrive at $TREE(3)$ would be indistinguishable of $TREE(3)$ itself.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but what is $f_{\Gamma_0}$?  I try to find the answer here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy but I didn't found....  Thank you!!

Comment: Check for example Saibians site : https://sites.google.com/site/largenumbers/home

Comment: The next major milestone above $f_{\omega}$ is $f_{\omega^2}$ , which grows like a Conway chain of $n$ $n's$ , then it continues to $f_{\omega^\omega}$ and so on until we arrive at $f_{\epsilon_0}$ which is nothing compared to $f_{\Gamma_0}$

Comment: You mean this: https://sites.google.com/site/largenumbers/home/4-2 ?

Comment: Even "insane huge" would not emphasize enough the magnitude of $TREE(3)$

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the chapter you can read to get a feeling for the fast growing hierarchy.

Comment: And BTW, what is the symbol "#" means? like `E100#^#100#(1+E100#^#100#3)` from here: https://sites.google.com/site/largenumbers/home/appendix/a/numbers3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79292/discussion-between-peter-and-yoar).

Comment: @CS1 See also: [David Metzler's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXliQvd1vW0&list=PL3A50BB9C34AB36B3) and [Giroux Studio's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vq2BxAJZ4Tc&list=PLUZ0A4xAf7nkaYHtnqVDbHnrXzVAOxYYC) videos on extremely large numbers. Also feel free to stop by in [my chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art) if you wish to discuss this with me.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers of the form $x\uparrow^y z$ are quite sparse. So while it's definitely possible to write a number larger than TREE(3) that way (not physically in our universe, but mathematically possible), I sincerely doubt any of them are *equal* to TREE(3).

Comment: I understand. We can also find $a,b$ such that: $a+b>TREE(3)$, but we can't write them at our universe :-) But you answer my question because when you wrote: _...not physically in our universe..._ - This what I look for!