# Question about $TREE(3)$ and Graham's Number

Tags: big-numbers, hyperoperation

Lets say: $G=\text{Graham's Number}$.
And:
$$
\begin{align*}
\alpha_1&=G\uparrow^G G,   \\
\alpha_2&=\alpha_1\uparrow^{\alpha_1} \alpha_1   \\
&\vdots\\
\beta_1 &= \alpha_G\uparrow^{\alpha_G}\alpha_G \\
\beta_2 &= \beta_1 \uparrow^{\beta_1 }\beta_1 \\
\beta_n &= \beta_{n-1} \uparrow^{\beta_{n-1} }\beta_{n-1}
\end{align*}
$$

> Then:
>   is $\beta_{\beta_G}$ still smaller then $TREE(3)$?

$a\uparrow^nb$ is [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)

Thank you!!

Comment: Is the choice of $\beta_{\beta_{G}}$ arbitrary or did you choose this specific value for a reason?

Comment: How do you define $\beta_n$?

Comment: Sidenote: this is likely much smaller than $\operatorname{TREE}(3)$ for the same reason as your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2830292).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, I add the the answer to my question, I hope it's much clear now :)

Comment: @aidangallagher4, kind of arbitrary - I try to find a way to came very close to TREE(3), so I thinking about ways, by using Graham Number notation, to aim the goal. Of course I can write something much bigger, but I want to know if it's enough (it's for something that I'm writing about it).

Comment: This number clearly does not reach $\large f_{\omega^3}$-level which is completely left in the dust by the $\large f_{\epsilon_0}$-level which is completely left in the dust by the $\large f_{\Gamma_0}$-level. And this last level is still nowehere near $TREE(3)$ , so the gap between your number and $TREE(3)$ is not just extremely huge, it is insanely huge.

Comment: See also: [Golf a number larger than TREE(3)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/139355)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. yes, I saw it from your profile! Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is much much smaller than $\operatorname{TREE}(3)$. To give you a rough taste, $G\approx f_{\omega+1}(64)$, and every application of $n\mapsto n\uparrow^nn$ only increases the inner argument by $1$, so $\alpha_n\approx f_{\omega+1}(64+n)$ and $\beta_n\approx f_{\omega+1}(64+G+n)\approx f_{\omega+1}(f_{\omega+1}(64)+64+n)$.

On the other hand, we have $f_{\omega+2}(n)=\overbrace{f_{\omega+1}(f_{\omega+1}(f_{\omega+1}(\dots f_{\omega+1}(}^nn)\dots)))$, so already $f_{\omega+2}(4)>\beta_{\beta_G}$.

In general,

$$f_{\alpha+1}(n)=\overbrace{f_\alpha(f_\alpha(f_\alpha(\dots f_\alpha(}^nn)\dots)))$$

so we likely have $f_{\omega+3}(3)=f_{\omega+2}(f_{\omega+2}(f_{\omega+2}(3)))$ to be much greater than your number.

On the other hand, $\operatorname{TREE}(n)\gtrapprox f_{\vartheta(\Omega^\omega\omega)}(n)$, which is significantly larger.

As a brief explanation of the fast growing hierarchy for a few more ordinals, we have

$$f_0(n)=n+1\\f_1(n)=2n\\f_2(n)=n2^n\\f_k(n)\gtrapprox2\uparrow^{k-1}n\\f_\omega(n)=f_n(n)\approx n\uparrow^nn\\f_{\omega2}(n)=f_{\omega+n}(n)\\f_{\omega k}(n)=f_{\omega(k-1)+n}(n)\\f_{\omega^2}(n)=f_{\omega n}(n)\\\vdots$$

In comparison, $\vartheta(\Omega^\omega\omega)\gg\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{.^{.^.}}}}\gg\omega^\omega\gg\omega^2$, which isn't anywhere near close to a good approximation to $\vartheta(\Omega^\omega\omega)$, which should tell you how frightening large this is.

For some introductions to the fast growing hierarchy, I recommend watching [David Metzler's videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXliQvd1vW0&list=PL3A50BB9C34AB36B3&index=1) or [Giroux Studio's videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vq2BxAJZ4Tc&list=PLUZ0A4xAf7nkaYHtnqVDbHnrXzVAOxYYC), and checking out [my chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337).