# What is the largest number used in a useful mathematical proof that isn't just an upper or lower bound?

Tags: soft-question, big-numbers

There are quite a few famous gigantic numbers used in useful mathematical proofs, like [Skewes's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number), [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number), and the number $2 \uparrow \uparrow 10^{10^6}$ from Coward and Lackenby's 2011 result on determining the ambient isotropy of links. However, these numbers are all upper (or lower) bounds, which I think is not quite as interesting, because you can often make an upper bound higher by just doing less work.

What is the largest number to have appeared naturally in a useful mathematical proof that isn't just an upper or lower bound? Obviously the terms "naturally" and "useful" make this question somewhat subjective. Also, I'm not particularly interested in numbers defined in the form "the smallest number satisfying $X$ property", so I'd prefer a number where we can actually estimate its value to some degree of precision - e.g. we can roughly estimate how many iterated logarithms (or another slowly-growing function) would be required to bring it down to $o(1)$. (I think this requirement would rule out [$\mathrm{TREE}(3)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem#TREE(3)).)

One possibility that occurs to me is $\sim 8 \times 10^{53}$, the cardinality of the monster group, but I bet there are larger ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the biggest number ever used in a mathematical proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497/what-is-the-biggest-number-ever-used-in-a-mathematical-proof)

Comment: If I'm being honest, I'd say that a) this question is too broad and subjective and b) you likely won't get really interesting answers (though hopefully this will not be the case)

Comment: As a sidenote: if one allows lower bounds, lower bounds to the Busy Beaver function (and variants) are quite large (some larger than TREE(3), for example)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The first paragraph of my question explains how it is distinct from the one you linked to.

Comment: I don't believe the linked dupe has any restriction that requires answers to be upper or lower bounds, so your question still falls as a subset of the linked one. I do see that perhaps the result may be different, with much smaller numbers here than the other, due to the restriction, but I still think anything here also belongs there; hence a dupe.

Comment: Might be of interest: http://ami.ektf.hu/uploads/papers/finalpdf/AMI_43_from29to41.pdf as well as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gijswijt%27s_sequence

Comment: Related: [What is the smallest constant that has explicitly appeared in a published paper?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98205/what-is-the-smallest-constant-that-has-explicitly-appeared-in-a-published-paper)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I don't see how this question "falls as a subset of the linked one." The biggest number ever used in a mathematical proof is almost certainly an upper bound. The largest non-upper-bound number (what I'm looking for) is therefore not the largest number (what they're looking for), so the correct answer to this question would be an incorrect answer to the other one, and it's clearly false that "anything here also belongs there".

Comment: You have a link for Coward and Lackenby's 2011 result on determining the ambient isotropy of links? Thanks.

Comment: @catsteevens https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2018/03/09/an-upper-bound-on-reidemeister-moves/amp/

Comment: @tparker "useful proof" must definitely be specified.